# How to replace NAs with subsequent numbers

Tags: r, replace, na

Lets say I have a Dataframe like

```
data.frame(A = c("P", "G", "P", "NA", "P", "NA", "G"),
B= c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "D"),
C =c("1", "5", "3", "3", "5", "4", "8"))
```

I would like to replace the NA in column A with subsequent numbers (e.g. The first NA is 1, second NA is 2 etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I found an Solution:

```
df$A[is.na(df$A)] <- (0:sum(is.na(df$A)))
```